# How do I deploy my personal website from flask?

Tags: html, web, deployment, flask, web-deployment

I just finished working on my personal website that I made via Flask, which I've been testing on a local host.

I've done a good amount of research on web hosts and have a domain that I bought awhile ago from Google Domains. It looks like iPage or GoDaddy would be my best options, but there is still a lot I'm confused about. The free trials for the web hosts I've tried out seem to be just website builders and don't have the option to deploy already completed websites.

Here's my questions:

1.) I have CSS, Python/Flask, and HTML files that I want to move to MyNameMyLastName.com. How do I make that happen?

2.) Can the domain I bought from Google Domains be used elsewhere?(GoDaddy, etc.)

Comment: Deploy the site on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryan,

You can use godaddy hosting, Host Gator, IX webhosting, there's tons of hosts..

Once you've decided on hosting, they will give you their DNS (Nameserver settings)
To use your domain from google to load your site, you will log into where you manage your domain you bought from google and change the nameservers to point to your current host.

Once you decide on your host, you will have FTP access, so you can put all your HTML, PHP, and other files on it.  If you're using a database, you can also import your data and settings as long as they support your framework.  MYSQL is probably the most common, but a lot of them support Wordpress, Joomla, and other frameworks.  I'm not sure about Flask, however, but that's something you can ask the hosting provider.

I'm unsure how this works with Google as of late, but I know for one of my businesses Google didn't offer hosting unless you used their crappy "google app site-builder" or something like that. HOWEVER, if you sign up with certain web hosting companies, a good bit of them will actually give you a free domain name for the first year.  If it's a yourwebsite.googlesites.com that your using right now, I would definitely take advantage of the free domain so you can make it "yourwebsite.com" and look more official.

It's kind of confusing the first time you do it, but most companies have support which will help you out.  (I know the hosts I just mentioned do)

Good luck

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks. However, what I have from Google Domains is a mywebsite.com that I actually paid for. Deleting the mywebsite.com wouldn't make that domain available for 30 days and I was hoping to have it up and running sooner. Do you know if I can still use that domain on GoDaddy/etc.?

Comment: You should be able to.  Once you buy hosting, all you should have to do is log into Google, go to where you can manage your domain, and set the nameservers to what your new hosting company gives you.

Comment: What that does is tell google that instead of using their server, you would like that domain to point to a different server.  If you purchased it, it's your domain, so you get to choose where it points.